AndroidのCameraXを用いた画像認識
以下CameraXのスタートガイドを基にカメラのプレビューを実装し、ImageAnalysisのユースケースから画像の文字認識を行っています。
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started?hl=ja#5
ここで得られた座標をカメラプレビューに重ねたカスタムビュー(Canvas)上にバウンディングボックスとして表示したいのですが座標がずれてしまいます。
ImageProxyは横向きで、width:600 height:480で保存されており、正しい位置にバウンドできていることを保存した画像から確認できました。
Canvasは縦向きで、width:1080 height:2185(タイトル部が335)となっており、canvasを中心座標を基に回転しても座標そのものを回転させて、アスペクト比を合わせてもずれてしまいます。
canvasを使うというのは標準的なやり方なのでしょうか？適切な実装方法を知りたいです。
以下環境で実行しています。
Xperia 10 III (SOG04)
Android 13
TargetSDK 34
kotolin 1.7.20

Canvasを重ねたうえでバウンディングボックスを正しい座標に表示することができました。
解決したのでクローズします
